# PL/SQL code to grant a new user select privs on views owned by another user

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, sql-grant

Need help with this...New to PL/SQL. Where am I going wrong?

```
 DECLARE

 CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE grant_view_privs

      IS sys_refcursor;
       strVIEWS Varchar2(1000);
       strQuery varchar2(4000);
  BEGIN

  open result for

    select object_name from user_objects where object_type='VIEW'
      and status !='INVALID';
   loop
     fetch result into strVIEWS;

  IF SQL%NOTFOUND then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('TABLE DOES NOT EXIST');

    ELSIF SQL%FOUND then

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Granting select on '||strVIEWS||' to BIOTICS_REPORT');

    strQuery := 'grant SELECT on '||strVIEWS||' to BIOTICS_REPORT';

    execute immediate strQuery;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUCCES');
    END IF;
end loop;

close result;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing a few things up here.

- If you're creating a stored procedure you don't start that with a `declare` keyword, that's for anonymous PL/SQL blocks.
- You're missing a variable name between `IS` and `sys_refcursor`; presumably that should be `result`.
- [`SQL%NOTFOUND`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#sthref531) will be true when there are no more rows in the result set; it does not indicate that there was no data at all, and certainly wouldn't indicate that the table (`user_objects`, which is actually a view) doesn't exist.
- Your loop will go on forever at the moment because you aren't detecting when you reach the end of the result set. You'll get sensible output from the `ELSE` part for all the views that do exist, but then it'll get `SQL%NOTFOUND` for each subsequent iteration; without an `exit` from the loop it will just try to fetch again.

If you're using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you can use the 'show errors' command to see why a stored block of code wouldn't compile, or you can query the `user_errors` view which will work in other clients too. But in this case that wouldn't have done much until you got past the `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"...` error from the `declare` being there. (It always heps if you actually state in the question what error you are getting).

I think this is the equivalent of what you seem to be aiming for:

```
create or replace procedure grant_view_privs is
  result sys_refcursor;
  strView user_objects.object_name%TYPE;
  strQuery varchar2(4000);
begin
  open result for
    select object_name
    from user_objects
    where object_type='VIEW'
    and status !='INVALID';
  loop
    fetch result into strView;
    exit when SQL%NOTFOUND;
    strQuery := 'grant SELECT on '||strView||' to BIOTICS_REPORT';
    dbms_output.put_line(strQuery);
    execute immediate strQuery;
  end loop;
  close result;
end grant_view_privs;
/
```

You can simplify that a bit with a different form of the [cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#BABDHAED) syntax:

```
create or replace procedure grant_view_privs is
  strQuery varchar2(4000);
begin
  for curViews in (
    select object_name
    from user_objects
    where object_type='VIEW'
    and status !='INVALID'
  )
  loop
    strQuery := 'grant SELECT on '||curViews.object_name||' to BIOTICS_REPORT';
    dbms_output.put_line(strQuery);
    execute immediate strQuery;
  end loop;
end grant_view_privs;
/
```

You don't even have to have `strQuery` defined if you generate the whole dynamic statement in the select:

```
create or replace procedure grant_view_privs is
begin
  for curViews in (
    select 'grant SELECT on '||object_name||' to BIOTICS_REPORT' as command
    from user_objects
    where object_type='VIEW'
    and status !='INVALID'
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(curViews.command);
    execute immediate curViews.command;
  end loop;
end grant_view_privs;
/
```